# digitalbush input mask position of cursor jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

***[DEMO](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)***

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:"mm/dd/yyyy"});
   $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
   $("#tin").mask("99-9999999");
   $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
});
```

I have tried using the digitalbush input mask. It is working ok.

The problem is , I wanted to make the cursor appear to the left most part of the input when the input is focused.I cant find a way to do this.Also i wanted to call the `.change();` event of the input by doing something like this

```
jQuery(function($){
       $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
       $("#phone").change();
    });
```

Unfortunately the event is not called.

1. How to place the cursor to left most part of input on focus.
2. Call event `.change()` of input after finish typing.

I tried making a demo but i cant make the maskedinput work. Please bear with it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#id").focus(function() {
    jQuery(function($) {
      $.mask.definitions["9"] = null;
      $.mask.definitions["^"] = "[0-9]";
      $.mask.definitions["N"] = "[N,V]";
      $("#id").mask("^^^-^^^-^^^-^^^N");
      $("#id").change();
    });
  });
  $("#id").change(function() {
    console.log('change')


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="id" name="" maxlength="20" class=" ">
```